# Lubuntu menu missing entries

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

`Menu` is not showing entries such as `Programming`, `Accessories` etc,

it has just `Run` and `Logout`.

`/usr/share/applications` have applications in it.

The most similar this I could find was this: https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=37060

But it didn't help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did it work before? If so, what changes have you made recently?  (I have messed around with Lubuntu menus a lot, so I can probably help, but need to know starting point)

Comment: Recently I ran out of disk space and was unable to login, then removed /tmp and /var/log to fix that and uninstalled a few Softwares. It was working fine for a while, then today I found out that menu entries are missing @OrganicMarble

Comment: Well, "removed a few softwares" could be scary or not, but here is some basic information. The system menu is at `/etc/xdg/menus/lxde-applications.menu` and the customized version is at `~/.config/menus/lxde-applications.menu` You could start by looking in that second place and see if it exists. If it does, rename it to something that doesn't end in .menu and restart your system. You should get the basic system menu. If you don't already have a custom menu, something deeper is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system menu is at `/etc/xdg/menus/lxde-applications.menu` and the customized version is at `~/.config/menus/lxde-applications.menu` You could start by looking in that second place and see if it exists. If it does, rename it to something that doesn't end in `.menu` and restart your system. You should get the basic system menu.

Comment: is there a place or resourse to learn more about this kind of stuff? :) I am always wonder how people know that much, is it just experience with working with Linux?  thank you!

Comment: In my case I wanted to customize the menus so I spend some time looking into how they worked. I did a lot of googling. Some information is here https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/adding-lxde-start-menu-sections/  I am no expert, I have just looked into some specific things. I made a lot of mistakes so I did learn how to get the basic menu back :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answer...
I didn't have `~/.config/menus/lxde-applications.menu` file, but wiping the contents of `~/.config/menus/` (`rm -rf ~/.config/menus/*`) and rebooting fixed the problem.

In my case `~/.config/menus/` contained `applications-merged` directory with 2 `.menu` files inside, 1 for Chrome and 1 for Xilinx. I don't know if these files were important and if erasing them caused any damage but I'm happy that I get the menu back.